# How to convert Unix Time to (dd-MMM-yyyy) with FTL code

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to convert a unix time to datetime depending on its locale given

Example I wanted to get locale Australia and convert UNIX time to date:

```
<#setting locale= getlocale>
<#assign unix = "1660545165"?number>
<#assign expiryDate = unix.getstarttime()?number?number_to_datetime?string["yyyy-mm-dd"]>
here is the time ${expiryDate}
```

I searched in google and suggested me to use getstarttime()?number?number_to_datetime?string["yyyy-mm-dd"]
However I am getting an error and currently stuck:
Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a number

Answer (score 1):

Lot of what's wrong I think is simply unnecessary there. Also based on the format you actually want a date, not a date-time. Here's a working example:

```
<#assign unixTime = 1660545165>
Here is the time: ${unixTime?number_to_date?string["yyyy-MM-dd"]}
```

Also usually you want to set the `date_format` setting to `yyyy-MM-dd` once (in the Java code, or with `<#setting date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd">` near the top of the the template), and then just write `${unixTime?number_to_date}` everywhere.

Comment: Note that `mm` are minutes and `MM` are months. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Ugh... right, `MM`, thanks for the fix!